# I have upload IPA in App Store but ipa is not upload in app store.some error show in app store

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have upload IPA in App Store but ipa is not upload in app store. Screen shot below.

[image: screen shot]

**Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness**

We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

```
crashlog-71EFC89F-83C5-443E-8954-377D5DDE3AFF.txt 
{
   "app_name":"Test Prep App",
   "timestamp":"2018-11-30 11:00:24.10 -0800",
   "app_version":"1.0.1",
   "slice_uuid":"a2647d83-95a1-35c5-8bcd-9be2b0ca063c",
   "adam_id":1441414601,
   "build_version":"1.0.3",
   "bundleID":"com.walescounseling.testprepapp",
   "share_with_app_devs":false,
   "is_first_party":false,
   "bug_type":"109",
   "os_version":"iPhone OS 12.1 (16B92)",
   "incident_id":"71EFC89F-83C5-443E-8954-377D5DDE3AFF",
   "name":"Test Prep App"
}


 Incident Identifier: 71EFC89F-83C5-443E-8954-377D5DDE3AFF 
 CrashReporter Key: 10f47639eb958afd3b96b7b0e3f1a9131d7d5ee5 
 Hardware Model: xxx Process: Test Prep App [2988] 
 Path: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE3FE572-7C85-4A14-B264-E1F3F2874A55/Test Prep App.app/Test Prep 
 App Identifier: com.xxxxx.testprepapp 
 Version: 1.0.3 (1.0.1) AppStoreTools: 10B63 C
 ode Type: ARM-64 (Native) 
 Role: Non UI 
 Parent Process: launchd [1] Coalition: com.walescounseling.testprepapp [1058] Date/Time: 2018-11-30 11:00:24.0350 -0800 
 Launch Time: 2018-11-30 11:00:23.0827 -0800 
 OS Version: iPhone OS 12.1 (16B92) 
 Baseband Version: n/a Report Version: 104 
 Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) 
 Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 
 Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY 
 Triggered by Thread: 8 
 Application Specific Information: abort() called 
 Last Exception Backtrace: (0x1ab957ea0 0x1aab29a40 0x1ab870d04 0x1ab95d7b8 0x1ab95f45c 0x10219eae4 0x10219eed0 0x10219ec38 0x10219e958 0x10219db24 0x10219c65c 0x10219ab2c 0x1ab3916c8 0x1ab392484 0x1ab3354a0 0x1ab341a28 0x1ab3422d0 0x1ab57417c 0x1ab576cec) 
 Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 
 Thread 0: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001ab4e3ed0 0x1ab4cc000 + 98000 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001ab4e33a8 0x1ab4cc000 + 95144 2 
 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab8e7bc4 0x1ab83c000 + 703428 3 
 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab8e2a60 0x1ab83c000 + 682592 4 
 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab8e21cc 0x1ab83c000 + 680396 5 
 GraphicsServices 0x00000001adb59584 0x1adb4e000 + 46468 6
  UIKitCore 0x00000001d8755054 0x1d7e6d000 + 9338964 7 
  Test Prep App 0x000000010210ec44 0x102108000 + 27716 8 libdyld.dylib 0x00000001ab3a2bb4 0x1ab3a2000 + 2996 
  Thread 1: 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576ce8 0x1ab568000 + 60648 
  Thread 2: 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576ce8 0x1ab568000 + 60648 
  Thread 3: 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576ce8 0x1ab568000 + 60648 
  Thread 4: 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576ce8 0x1ab568000 + 60648 
  Thread 5: 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576ce8 0x1ab568000 + 60648 
  Thread 6: 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576ce8 0x1ab568000 + 60648 
  Thread 7 name: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread 
  Thread 7: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001ab4e3ed0 0x1ab4cc000 + 98000 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001ab4e33a8 0x1ab4cc000 + 95144 2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab8e7bc4 0x1ab83c000 + 703428 3 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab8e2a60 0x1ab83c000 + 682592 4 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab8e21cc 0x1ab83c000 + 680396 5 Foundation 0x00000001ac2d7404 0x1ac2cf000 + 33796 6 Foundation 0x00000001ac2d72b0 0x1ac2cf000 + 33456 7 UIKitCore 0x00000001d8842808 0x1d7e6d000 + 10311688 8 Foundation 0x00000001ac40a1ac 0x1ac2cf000 + 1290668 9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab5732ac 0x1ab568000 + 45740 10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab57320c 0x1ab568000 + 45580 11 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576cf4 0x1ab568000 + 60660 
  Thread 8 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos 
  Thread 8 Crashed: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001ab4ef104 0x1ab4cc000 + 143620 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab56a070 0x1ab568000 + 8304 2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00000001ab446d78 0x1ab3ef000 + 359800 3 libc++abi.dylib 0x00000001aab10f78 0x1aab0f000 + 8056 4 libc++abi.dylib 0x00000001aab11120 0x1aab0f000 + 8480 5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001aab29e48 0x1aab23000 + 28232 6 libc++abi.dylib 0x00000001aab1d0fc 0x1aab0f000 + 57596 7 libc++abi.dylib 0x00000001aab1d188 0x1aab0f000 + 57736 8 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001ab392498 0x1ab331000 + 398488 9 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001ab3354a0 0x1ab331000 + 17568 10 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001ab341a28 0x1ab331000 + 68136 11 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001ab3422d0 0x1ab331000 + 70352 12 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab57417c 0x1ab568000 + 49532 13 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576cec 0x1ab568000 + 60652 
  Thread 9: 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576ce8 0x1ab568000 + 60648 
  Thread 10: 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576ce8 0x1ab568000 + 60648 
  Thread 11: 0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576ce8 0x1ab568000 + 60648 
  Thread 12 name: JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger 
  Thread 12: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001ab4eef0c 0x1ab4cc000 + 143116 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab56bcd8 0x1ab568000 + 15576 2 libc++.1.dylib 0x00000001aaabc568 0x1aaab4000 + 34152 3 JavaScriptCore 0x00000001b2c8ffd8 0x1b2c2e000 + 401368 4 JavaScriptCore 0x00000001b2c8fe88 0x1b2c2e000 + 401032 5 JavaScriptCore 0x00000001b2c8eb24 0x1b2c2e000 + 396068 6 JavaScriptCore 0x00000001b2c8e1e0 0x1b2c2e000 + 393696 7 JavaScriptCore 0x00000001b2c8fc8c 0x1b2c2e000 + 400524 8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab5732ac 0x1ab568000 + 45740 9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab57320c 0x1ab568000 + 45580 10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576cf4 0x1ab568000 + 60660 
  Thread 13 name: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader 
  Thread 13: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001ab4e3ed0 0x1ab4cc000 + 98000 1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001ab4e33a8 0x1ab4cc000 + 95144 2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab8e7bc4 0x1ab83c000 + 703428 3 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab8e2a60 0x1ab83c000 + 682592 4 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab8e21cc 0x1ab83c000 + 680396 5 CFNetwork 0x00000001abf03834 0x1abf02000 + 6196 6 Foundation 0x00000001ac40a1ac 0x1ac2cf000 + 1290668 7 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab5732ac 0x1ab568000 + 45740 8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab57320c 0x1ab568000 + 45580 9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ab576cf4 0x1ab568000 + 60660 
  Thread 8 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit): x0: 0x0000000000000000 x1: 0x0000000000000000 x2: 0x0000000000000000 x3: 0x000000028214c037 x4: 0x00000001aab20b81 x5: 0x000000016e1529e0 x6: 0x000000000000006e x7: 0xffffffffffffffec x8: 0x0000000000000c00 x9: 0x00000001ab56e870 x10: 0x00000001ab569ef4 x11: 0x0000000000000003 x12: 0x0000000000000000 x13: 0x0000000000000000 x14: 0x0000000000000010 x15: 0x0000000000000007 x16: 0x0000000000000148 x17: 0x0000000000000000 x18: 0x0000000000000000 x19: 0x0000000000000006 x20: 0x000000016e153000 x21: 0x000000016e1529e0 x22: 0x000000000000a60b x23: 0x000000016e1530e0 x24: 0x000000016e1530e0 x25: 0x0000000000000000 x26: 0x00000000000005ff x27: 0x00000001e498bf00 x28: 0x0000000002ffffff fp: 0x000000016e152940 lr: 0x00000001ab56a070 sp: 0x000000016e152910 pc: 0x00000001ab4ef104 cpsr: 0x00000000 Binary Images: 0x102108000 - 0x10252ffff Test Prep App arm64 <a2647d8395a135c58bcd9be2b0ca063c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE3FE572-7C85-4A14-B264-E1F3F2874A55/Test Prep App.app/Test Prep App 0x1026c8000 - 0x10272bfff dyld arm64 <fc36be383ccf330abe42940868e68937> /usr/lib/dyld 0x1029c8000 - 0x1029d3fff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64 <a8cd788cc9113887ae254bd47d58c7c1> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib 0x1aaab2000 - 0x1aaab3fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64 <b3dbcc8e41b03e51b7e65d2800dcdea9> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 0x1aaab4000 - 0x1aab0efff libc++.1.dylib arm64 <c406443c983a33829b164c441b7c2af4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib 0x1aab0f000 - 0x1aab22fff libc++abi.dylib arm64 <311c3f6ae6de347a8f9d9be875f3c557> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib 0x1aab23000 - 0x1ab2abfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64 <823edfdc3149335c86f850561fec2c3c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib 0x1ab2ac000 - 0x1ab2b1fff libcache.dylib arm64 <e9bd17104b5e38658669ca9856df215b>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow sujeet, please elaborate little more what's the problem

Comment: You are using JavaScriptCore, maybe it's a React Native or Ionic project? I guess the problem is in the Javascript "world" side...

Comment: @shadowsheep -- Ionic project

Comment: @ shesh nath - Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to install the ipa on a iOS 12.1 device and see if it crashes?